# Error: Unknown column 'makeId' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting a Unknown column 'makeId' in 'field list' when I used the INSERT to take info from tables and put it in the vehicleNormal.

```
INSERT INTO vehicleNormal (makeId, modelId, year, cylinders, driveId, mpgHighway, mpgCity, fueltypeId)
(SELECT makeId, modelId, year, cylinders, driveId, mpgH, mpgC, fueltypeId
FROM vehicle
JOIN vehicleMake ON vehicle.make = vehicleMake.make
JOIN vehicleModel ON vehicle.model = vehicleModel.model
JOIN vehicleDrive ON vehicle.drive = vehicleDrive.drive
JOIN vehicleFuelType ON vehicle.fueltype = vehicleFuelType.fueltype);
```

When my table has the 'makeId'...

```
CREATE TABLE ‘vehicleNormal’ (
‘vehicleId’ INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
‘fuelType’ VARCHAR (255) DEFAULT NULL,
‘makeId’ INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
‘modelId’ INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
‘year’ INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
‘cylinders’ INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
‘driveId’ INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
‘mpgHighway’ DECIMAL(10,2),
PRIMARY KEY (‘vehicleId’)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Any help would be great. :/

Comment: It is in `vehicleNormal`, but it is not in any of the other tables.  The error probably refers to the `select`.

Comment: So you think it can't find the makeId in the other tables?

Answer (score 1):

Just added the vehicle. to all the columns in SELECT. Thank you Gordon Linoff for pointing me in the right direction.

```
INSERT INTO vehicleNormal (makeId, modelId, year, cylinders, driveId, mpgHighway, mpgCity, fueltypeId)
(SELECT vehicle.make, vehicle.model, vehicle.year, vehicle.cylinders, vehicle.drive, vehicle.mpgHighway, vehicle.mpgCity, vehicle.fueltype
FROM vehicle
JOIN vehicleMake ON vehicle.make = vehicleMake.make
JOIN vehicleModel ON vehicle.model = vehicleModel.model
JOIN vehicleDrive ON vehicle.drive = vehicleDrive.drive
JOIN vehicleFuelType ON vehicle.fueltype = vehicleFuelType.fueltype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided the table definition for the destination table in the INSERT, but not for the source tables. The SELECT will generate the error if a field called makeId does not exist in the source tables.